# Send message to my linkedIn contact using Mathematica 10.3

Tags: social-media

I am trying to send message to my LinkedIn contact using Mathematica 10.3, but there is no enough information (documented) on how to do that. I am able to login in LinkedIn and see my user data with:

```
lk = ServiceConnect["LinkedIn"]     (* works fine *)
ud=ServiceExecute[lk, "UserData"]; (* works fine *)

ServiceExecute[lk, "GroupNames", "Count" -> "3"] (* Nothing happens ...*)
```

1) What are the commands to send a simple message to a specific contact of mine?

2) Where can I find more information about connecting to LinkedIn using Mathematica (Mathematica's Help is very limited)?

Answer (score 7):

Long story short, LinkedIn changed their API and what it can do. The documentation needs to be updated and the function probably needs to be changed a bit.

"UserData" and "Share" requests should work, but the rest won't.

The syntax for creating messages should look something like this:

```
ServiceExecute[LIN, "Share", "Message" -> "This is a test message"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently Mathematica supports two LinkedIn requests.
1."UserData"
2. "Share".

Earlier more requests used to be supported but change in linkedin policies caused others to take back seat. Also currently it is not possible to share a message to other members in your linkedin network.

[image]